# Defining circular area around fixed location?

Tags: coordinate-system

I was trying to define a circular area around a fixed location, with known latitude and longitude. The radius of the circle will be less than 90 m. I want to get an array of all the locations present in that area. My main aim is when two or more circles intersect then to get all the location coordinates(i.e. latitude and longitude), which are present in both the circles(i.e. the intersecting area).

That's my approach, I am a beginner in this GIS field.

Comment: What GIS software are you using? The circular area you're referring to is typically called a "buffer" in GIS, the intersecting area function you describe is (conveniently) called Intersect in ArcGIS.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.

Answer (score 0):

This all assumes you're using arcGIS. If you are using QGIS, the process is similar, but the tools are named differently and in different locations.

Create a point shapefile containing the points you wish to create the circles from. When creating points in editing mode, right click and create the point using Absolute X and Y. You can type in the coordinates you want exactly.

Buffer your points with the Buffer tool by whatever size radius you want. 90m? 
With your two circles, you can intersect the two circles leaving just the portion that overlaps.

Create a point shape file of the other points you wish to analyse.
Do a Select by Location, those points that are within the intersect polygon.

EDIT: If you need to know the coordinates of the points that are in the intersect, you can create an X field and a Y field and calculate geometry on them.

Comment: There are two possible solutions to op. Intersect points with buffers (output points) and spatial join one to many. Your solution is about something else.

Comment: How do you figure that? He wants all the points in the area of intersection of  two overlapping circles created from a couple of points. This does that. I mean your's does too.

Comment: He says two or more. How is your solution helps here?